# MongoDB & Mongoose accessing one database while authenticating against another (NodeJS, Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a few databases and didn't want to create separate user accounts for each one. MongoDB supports the notion of authenticating access to a database using accounts defined in another database but examples of syntax are hard to come by.

I was on the verge of posting a question when i finally figured it out. Here goes in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 8):

Here's the syntax for a mongodb, mongoose, node setup.

1. Create the database user in the admin database from the mongo shell

   `use admin`

   `db.addUser( { user: "mydbuser", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [ ] } )`
2. Create the database and add the user - the userSource indicates that
   the credentials are defined in the admin database

   `use mydb`
   `db.addUser( { user: "mydbuser", userSource: "admin" , roles: [ "readWrite" , "dbAdmin"] } )`
3. Specify the auth parameter in the mongoose connection string

   `var myDB = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://mydbuser:mypassword@myipaddress:27017/mydb" ,{auth:{authdb:"admin"}});`

   the option {auth:...} is what specifies that the user account must be authenticated against the admin db.
4. Similarly to connect to the database from the mongo shell

   `mongo myipaddr:27017/mydb -u "mydbuser" -p "mypassword"`

Note: The user "mydbuser" had only read/write and admin access to mydb. you can find more information on user privileges [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/). A fuller example of the scenario is [here](http://learningmean.blogspot.com/2013/10/mongodb-single-user-account-for.html)

Comment: userSource field is removed from v2.6 in the createUser method. Can you guide me to the createUser method equivalent of the post?

Comment: This information is no longer correct in recent versions of mongo.

Answer (score 4):

This can also can be simplified by modifying the connection string in the mongodb itself:

For eg: ***mongodb://username:password@IP:Port/mydbname?authSource=admin*** since mongoose supports this connection string provided by **mongodb** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource